# How can I flip an image along the vertical axis with python?

Tags: python

I am trying to flip a picture across its vertical axis in python.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For something as simple as this, PIL is not really needed - you can do it with numpy `fliplr`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

im = np.flipud(plt.imread('so.jpg'))
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.imshow(im)
plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.imshow(np.fliplr(im))
plt.show()
```

[image]

wolf revok cats !

Comment: Thanks, but how would i do with with using the media library?

Comment: sorry, I meant the pygraphics Library, http://packages.python.org/PyGraphics/user/index.html

Comment: Don't know, never used that library.  Is the method above unsatisfactory for some reason?

Comment: its fine, but i never been exposed to PIL, thats why i am trying to figure out if i can do it using the PyGraphics, I am planning on writing an algorithms that takes each pixel and moves them

Comment: But this is a `numpy` trick, not `PIL`.  If you want to do it in `PIL`, see @Lattyware answer.

Comment: Given the documentation from PyGraphics states you need both numpy and PIL installed for PyGraphics, I'd say both are valid options. I'd argue the PIL option is, however, clearer and simpler in this context given that PyGraphics loads the image as a PIL object.

Answer (score 4):

You have stated you are using PyGraphics - it states that `load_image` [returns a PIL image object](http://packages.python.org/PyGraphics/user/picture.html#picture.load_image).

PyGraphics doesn't appear to offer the functionality of flipping, so just do it with [PIL](http://effbot.org/zone/pil-index.htm), specifically [`transpose`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.transpose)

```
from PyGraphics import picture
flipped = picture.load_image("blah.jpg").transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the PIL for such things :)

http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

This may be the simplest way to do what you wan.

Here is a tutorial that will give the code :

http://effbot.org/imagingbook/introduction.htm
(see chapter geometric transforms in the tutorial)